# Bigblue-Greenlight Docker Rebuild is not reflecting changes added to files in app

Tags: bigbluebutton

Let say i have in my bigblue-greenlight installation following files:

```
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root 4096 May 6 19:04 .
drwx------ 10 root root 4096 May 6 18:47 ..
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root 4096 May 6 17:45 app
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May 6 17:45 bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 934 May 6 17:45 cloudbuild-dev.yaml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 906 May 6 17:45 cloudbuild.yaml
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 May 6 17:45 config
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 230 May 6 17:45 config.ru
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 May 6 18:11 db
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 830 May 6 17:45 docker-compose.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1702 May 6 17:45 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 286 May 6 17:45 .dockerignore
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8246 May 6 18:10 .env
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3678 May 6 19:04 Gemfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 9831 May 6 17:45 Gemfile.lock
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 May 6 18:04 .git
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 858 May 6 17:45 .gitignore
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1665 May 6 17:45 .gitlab-ci.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 945 May 6 17:45 greenlight.nginx
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 May 6 17:45 lib
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7652 May 6 17:45 LICENSE
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May 6 18:13 log
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May 6 17:45 public
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 394 May 6 17:45 Rakefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 578 May 6 17:45 .rake_tasks~
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2400 May 6 17:45 README.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 53 May 6 17:45 .rspec
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3426 May 6 17:45 .rubocop.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6 May 6 17:45 .ruby-version
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8020 May 6 17:45 sample.env
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May 6 17:45 scripts
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 May 6 17:45 spec
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 May 6 17:45 test
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May 6 17:45 tmp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1325 May 6 17:45 .travis.yml
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 May 6 17:45 vendor
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 86 May 6 17:45 yarn.lock
```

I have modify my application or service under folder **"app"**.

Which command should i use to update the service to reflect my application changes ?

Please could anybody provide the command to this one ?

My file docker-compose.yml has nothing particulary:

```
...
services:
  app:
    entrypoint: [bin/start]
    image: bigbluebutton/greenlight:v2
    ...
 ...
```

Comment: I am having difficulty fully understanding your question. Assuming you have made changes to the greenlight code in  in the greenlight source folder 'app' then to "reflect my application changes" you would follow the instructions here https://docs.bigbluebutton.org/greenlight/gl-customize.html#customizing-greenlight specifically for docker compose here https://docs.bigbluebutton.org/greenlight/gl-customize.html#using-docker-compose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to make the changes inside that one container, then restart this one Docker container.

```
docker exec -it container_id bash
```

Make changes, then exit

```
docker restart container_id
```

But I'm sure this is not the best way to do it.